# Property from link scope is anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I write custom directive.

In this peace of code I want to get property from scope

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            user: '=',
            startDate: '=',
            daysInRow: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            days = $rootScope.days[scope.user.id]; <-- here Id is undefined
```

I want to get `user` and from it `id` but `user` is "anonymous function".
Other properties 'startDate' and 'daysInRow' is binded correctly

I know that correctly bind values in template

```
<div am-calendar-row user="user" start-date="calendar.startDay" days-in-row="calendar.numberDays"></div>
```

In what is my problem?

User object :

```
admin:false
approver:false
defaultNotificationRecipient:false
defaultRecipient:false
defaultedNotifiers:null
defaultedRecepients:null
email:"sergiy.aleks@gmail.com"
endDate:Fri Feb 21 2014 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)
id:4
initialValue:8
name:"Sergiy Aleks"
requestToUserCount:0
roles:Array[0]
startDate:Mon Sep 27 2010 15:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
unAnsweredRequestToUserCount:0
userId:4
userRequestCount:0
vacationRate:0
```

And `console.log(scope.user);` returns next :

```
function (a){return h(c,a)}
```

---

UPDATE : As I noticed, this is caused by `ng-repeat` and `track by $index`. When I set `track by user.id` then I get another error :

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: user in (filteredUsers = (users | orderBy:'name' | filter:inSelectedGroups:user | filter:workTheseMonths) ) track by user.id, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: {"$$state":{"status":0}}

But `id`s should be unique, so this error is unknow for me.

In `ng-repeat` I use `user` value to pass to my directive.

---

UPDATE 2 :

When I've used `track by $index` only top 4 users return `scope.user` as function, the others return object.

---

UPDATE 3 :

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="user in (filteredUsers = (users | orderBy:'name' | filter:inSelectedGroups:user | filter:workTheseMonths) ) track by user.id" ng-if="!user.visible">
                ...
                <div class="calendar-slider date-wrap" style="  margin-left: 15px;" ng-style="calendarOffset">
                    <div class="calendar-wrapper">
                        <div am-calendar-row user="user" start-date="calendar.startDay" days-in-row="calendar.numberDays"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And prove, that in `users` collection I haven't functions - [image]

Comment: If it's a function you need to bind it to the scope using `&` rather than `=`

Comment: @AlonEitan, but `user` is element in collection. I use collection `users` in `ng-repeat` and it works good. Just for this directive I get error. By the way, I've tried `&` but nothing changed

Comment: What is the value of user? Can you update with what the user object you're injecting contains

Comment: As @KieranDotCo - what do you see in your directive when you do `console.log(scope.user);`?

Comment: So user is indeed a function and not an object. This function expect a parameter, can you describe what this parameter is?

Comment: I might be way off, but is there another function inside the scope named user ?

Comment: @AlonEitan  please check update.

Comment: @M22an please check update

Comment: @demo Can you please include all the `ngRepeat` view in the question, and show us how the collection is structured? Also, as @M22an wrote, is it possible you also have a `scope.user = function()...` in your directive?

Comment: @AlonEitan, about `function()` - No, only `user` like field